# list emails from specific folder with Microsoft365R's list_emails

Tags: r, microsoft365r

Is there anyway to specify a folder instead of just listing the emails in the Inbox?

Example for listing items in the Inbox:

```
library(Microsoft365R)

outlb <- get_business_outlook()
emlst <- outlb$list_emails()
```

Can't find anything in the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/Microsoft365R.pdf) about how to point this to a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
outlb <- get_business_outlook()
emls_from_folder <- outlb$get_folder("name_of_folder")$list_emails()
```